# npm update failed and after running create-react-app few files such as public, App.js index.js etc are not installing

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, windows-10, create-react-app

when I run the npx-create-react-app it creates only the files of package-json, node modules, and package-lock.json. whereas,app.js, index.js, and public files are not creating for react app.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AsCn.jpg It shows npm update failed I tried deleting the config store files but it didn't resolve the issue. npm and node are in the current version. I tried all the methods like deleting config store files and reinstalling node, using yarn, uninstalling npm, and updating npm to the latest version but nothing worked. My issue resolved by resuming the cmd.exe which was suspending but I have to do it every time I create react app on how to fix this?
.

Comment: Hey i created the repo for new react app where you not need to generate new React App just clone the file and start working on it @Anushree

Comment: Or ping me in skype will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common problem please refer to this GitHub repository you can easily solve your issue by using this create-react-app they made for us to configure easily.

URL: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: My cmd.exe was suspending in the middle I resumed it that resolved the issue after trying every possible solution this finally worked